# Understanding different types of ground (and KiCad 6)

Tags: ground, kicad

In the follow picture, I attached a snippet of a schematic which I am trying to port to KiCad and ultimately modify for my own purposes. I'm noticing, however, that there are at least four different types of ground here (FG, PG, DG, and AG) which are used at various points throughout the circuit.

I was able to surmise that AG and DG *probably* correspond to Analog Ground and Digital Ground in KiCad, but I'm at a total loss as to what the other two even are.

Can anyone shed some light on to what these different things stand for, and what they might correspond to in KiCad? If I actually know what they are, I could probably look up their functional differences.

[image: a small schematic snippet which shows different ground types]

Comment: frame and power

Comment: Ground symbols in kicad are just labels to help you organize your schematic. They have no meaning and aside from being hard to read you could label them A,B,C, and D if you wanted. Rather than try and replicate the exact graphical style, what the schematic is suggesting you do is look very carefully at those parts of your larger ground net and then route them such that 3 of the grounds meet at a single point. The fourth is apparently not so important.

Answer (score 1):

I would surmise that `PG` stands for "Power Ground".  `FG` is a bit of a mystery but the symbol there indicates that it connects with the off-board ground.

Here's a summary of the different symbols and what they are commonly used for:  [KiCAD 5 --- what is the significance of the various GND symbols?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392911/kicad-5-what-is-the-significance-of-the-various-gnd-symbols/392977#392977)

Comment: FG would be "Frame (or case) Ground" - it would connect to the surrounding metal bits of the device.